# Route url query params individual characters as object values instead of one long string

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

I have an app with a purchase journey that renders a component with a `webview` element to display a web page to select a product. Upon selecting a product you are redirected to a new component to process the order, which has another `webview` element.

The issue I'm having is that I am expecting `route.params.url` to contain the url that has been navigated to, however this doesn't appear to be the case...

Logging out `route` gives the `key`, `name` and `params`, but the params is an object with each individual character of the url's query params as a new key/value pair - Keys are the index of the character position.

For example, say the url received by my component is `some-link.com?test=hello` I would receive:

```
{
    key": "ComponentName-some-uuid",
    "name": "ComponentName",
    params: {
        0: '?',
        1: 't',
        2: 'e',
        3: 's',
        4: 't',
        5: '=',
        6: 'h',
        7: 'e',
        8: 'l',
        9: 'l',
        10: 'o'
    }
}
```

Is there any reason for this?

The webview element is being used as:

```
        <WebView
          source={{ uri: url }}
          // ... More stuff
        />
```